# How to set right path of property file?

Tags: java, web-applications, path, properties-file

I have a problem I can't resolve.
I need to read properties file, but can't set right path.
Documentation of java.io.File is saying that I have to set in from the src/...
It doesnt work, I did a path from current file and have the same problem.

**EXCEPTION IS : FileNotFound**

*PropertyReader class:*

```
public final class PropertyReader {

    private Properties prop = new Properties();
    private InputStream input = null;

    public Properties getProperties(File file) {
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(file);
            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (null != input) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

And ApplicationController.class which uses PropertyReader:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/result", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String resultPage(ModelMap model) {
    //Getting property with key "path"
    model.addAttribute("path", new PropertyReader().getProperties(file).getProperty("path"));
    return "result";
```

If I'm setting path from C://.. it works fine.

[image: Project structure]

Thank you much and have a nice day!

Comment: Put the properties file in resources folder

Comment: How did you create your `File` object

Comment: File file = new File(" here path to file");

Comment: Properties are in resource folder, u can find in at Project Structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I resolved it by using annotations  @PropertySource and @Value()**

*For example:*

`//There could be any folder
     @PropertySource("classpath:file.properties")
     public class AnyClass {
        //There could be any property
        @Value("${some.property}")
        private String someValue;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Following example to read property file.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);

        // get the property value and print it out
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("mysqldb"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Its also depends on the framework that you are using like SpringMVC, JSF and Struts. All these framework have their own shortcut ways to access property files.

Comment: I'm using SpringMVC, anyway your answer the same as my PropertyReader.class.